# Do I need all 32 copies of the nVidia drivers under C:\RecoveryImage\?

Tags: windows-10

I noticed I was running annoyingly close to being out of space on my system SSD. I fire up WinDirStat and notice this: what are ostensibly 32 copies of the nVidia drivers, all alike, all slightly different, totalling over 10 GB of data.

> [image: 32 copies of the nVidia drivers, all alike, all different.]
>
> <sup>[(Click for animation](https://gfycat.com/ConcreteWelldocumentedImperialeagle))</sup>

Do I need, or want, to hold onto all of those copies? Which ones can I rid myself of?

Comment: You really don't want to delete files out of that folder.

Comment: @Ramhound I honestly doubt I have even 2 of those actually installed right now. I do not anticipate needing to roll back my graphics card drivers to 30 versions ago, and if I did, _I could just download them._

Comment: Except all those files and the exact same date which is odd.  I cannot suggest removing the files for that reason.

Comment: @Ramhound The fact they're all dated _March_ (edit) and _May_ (creation) makes me even more confident I can rid myself of them.

Comment: What is the full path to this folder.  I cannot find a `RecoveryImage` folder on my machine.  Given that its a root directory.  You can delete the entire, I didn't notice, the path in the title before.